# How to share big images on facebook, instead of thumbnail and blog title and description

Tags: php, wordpress-theming

I could really use some help on this one, its driving me nuts.

Im creating an image site in wordpress, and I would like my post to be shared, with only big images on Facebook. Kinda like a .gif but the image files are .jpg nor .png

To clearify what i need, take a look at this:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdansk-humor.dk%2Fphotogallery.php%3Fphoto_id%3D59

I really dont care about the faults, Just want to share big images.
So the site im linking to is a PHP fuision site. Ive talked to the guy that runs it. And ive gotten the code from him.

The code look like this;

```js
if ($data['photo_gif']=="1")
{
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:image" content="'.$settings['siteurl'].''.$photo_file.'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:image:width" content="'.$photo_size[0].'" />');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:image:height" content="'.$photo_size[1].'" />');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:title" content="'.$data['photo_title'].'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:description" content="'.$settings['description'].'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:url" content="'.$settings['siteurl'].''.$photo_file.'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:type" content="video.movie">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:video" content="'.$settings['siteurl'].''.$photo_file.'">');

}
else
{
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:image" content="'.$settings['siteurl'].''.$photo_file.'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:image:width" content="'.$photo_size[0].'" />');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:image:height" content="'.$photo_size[1].'" />');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:title" content="'.$data['photo_title'].'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:description" content="'.$settings['sitename'].'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:url" content="'.$settings['siteurl'].'photogallery.php?photo_id='.$_GET['photo_id'].'">');
  add_to_head('<meta property="og:type" content="website" />');

}
```

On his site, he has the option to pick if he want to share big images or not. I just want my site to only share big images. 
He said that the key point is to make the og:image and the og:url the same. Using the image path.

So i tried to do this, what wordpress echo strings. This is my code:

```js
function doctype_opengraph($output) {
    return $output . '
    xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"
    xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
}
add_filter('language_attributes', 'doctype_opengraph');
function fb_opengraph() {
    global $post;
 
    if(is_single()) {
        if(has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) {
            $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full');
        } else {
            $img_src = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'http://dinfrækert.dk/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/dinfraekert_dk.png';
        }
        if($excerpt = $post->post_excerpt) {
            $excerpt = strip_tags($post->post_excerpt);
            $excerpt = str_replace("", "'", $excerpt);
        } else {
            $excerpt = get_bloginfo('description');
        }
        ?>
 
    <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo the_title(); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $excerpt; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo(); ?>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/>
 <meta property="og:video" content="<?php echo $img_src; ?>"/>
 
<?php
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'fb_opengraph', 5);
```

This is kinda working. Well not really. but its give me some kind of output. 
This is what it looks like i post sourcecode after implamentet the script. Ive putted it in functions.php btw.

```html
  <meta property="og:title" content="Kravlenisse."/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Frække og sjove ting dagligt"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="Array"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Din frækkert"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="Array"/>
 <meta property="og:video" content="Array"/>
```

Im getting the "Array" fault. 
Really hoping someone could help me!

Comment: <meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="400" />

Comment: Just tried that, no luck, thanks

Comment: 1 - go to this page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/ and enter your website url and click on fetch again here you will get your problem solution

Comment: Thanks Sagar. But I dont mind the faults. I just want the debug to show the big images, with no title or description. My image patch its nok working, Cant figure out whats wrong. Using wordpress echo strings. My code works with the title and description, just not the image.